# Выполнение python на php

Tags: php, python

Как с помощью php запустить следующий скрипт?

Из bash shell это запускается так:

```
cd /root/audio-recognition-quick-trial-master/
python test.py song.mp3
```

Comment: unrelated: на Питоне: `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'test.py', 'song.mp3'], cwd='/root/audio-recognition-quick-trial-master/')`, если хочется дочерний скрипт запустить используя ту же версию Питона, что и родитель.

Comment: А можно подробнее объяснить? Я с питоном не знаком

Comment: это просто код, который показывает как запустить внешную команду (другой скрипт в данном случае) на Питоне, для сравнения. Если добавить `import subprocess, sys`, то это полный код.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = getcwd();
chdir('/root/audio-recognition-quick-trial-master/');
$out = shell_exec('python test.py song.mp3');
chdir($path);
echo $out;
```

Comment: Результат чистый лист

Comment: добавьте echo $out;

Comment: Тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот попробуйте

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('python /root/audio-recognition-quick-trial-master/test.py /root/audio-recognition-quick-trial-master/song.mp3', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

https://www.php.net/system

http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Comment: Результат Last line of the output:
Return value: 2                 А должно  быть название песни